# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-unicode

I am trying to pull a list of 500 restaurants in Amsterdam from TripAdvisor; however after the 308th restaurant I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dtrinh/PycharmProjects/TripAdvisorData/LinkPull-HK.py", line 43, in <module>
    writer.writerow(rest_array)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried several things I found on StackOverflow, but nothing is working as of right now. I was wondering if someone could take a look at my code and see any potential solutions that would be great.

```
        for item in soup2.findAll('div', attrs={'class', 'title'}):
            if 'Cuisine' in item.text:
                item.text.strip()
                content = item.findNext('div', attrs=('class', 'content'))
                cuisine_type = content.text.encode('utf8', 'ignore').strip().split(r'\xa0')
        rest_array = [account_name, rest_address, postcode, phonenumber, cuisine_type]
        #print rest_array
        with open('ListingsPull-Amsterdam.csv', 'a') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow(rest_array)
    break
```

Comment: `cuisine_type` is a list because you use `.split` (and I'm not sure why you're splitting on non-break spaces...). However, the contents of a row that you pass to `.writerow` need to be strings or numbers. Also, when using the Python 2 `csv` module you're supposed to open the CSV files in binary mode, as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `rest_array` contains unicode strings. When you use `csv.writer` to write rows, you need to serialise bytes strings (you are on Python 2.7).

I suggest you to use "utf8" encoding:

```
with open('ListingsPull-Amsterdam.csv', mode='a') as fd:
    writer = csv.writer(fd)
    rest_array = [text.encode("utf8") for text in rest_array]
    writer.writerow(rest_array)
```

*note: please, don't use `file` as variable because you shadow the built-in function `file()` (an alias of `open()` function).*

If you want to open this CSV file with Microsoft Excel, you may consider using another encoding, for instance "cp1252" (it allows u"\u2019" character).

Answer (score 4):

You're writing a non-ascii character(s) to your csv output file. Make sure you open the output file with the appropriate character encoding that allows for the character(s) to be encoded. A safe bet is often UTF-8. Try this:

```
with open('ListingsPull-Amsterdam.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(rest_array)
```

*edit* this is for Python 3.x, sorry.

Comment: I think he won't have this error on Python 3. His question is tagged `python-2.7`.

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines at the start of your script

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```