# 'ascii' codec can't encode character error

Tags: python, csv, ms-access, pyodbc

I request your kind assistance in tackling an error. I am trying to save MS Access database tables as CSV files using Python. I seem to be running into an error I do not know how to fix. I have looked through different posts on Stack overflow and tried them but nothing fulfilling. Please provide your kind assistance.

```
import pyodbc
import csv

conn_string = ("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Access\\permissions.accdb") 

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from [Perm_Site Info];")

with open('C:\\Desktop\\Python Files\\Perms_Site_Info.csv','wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    rest_array = [text.encode("utf8") for text in cursor]
    writer.writerow(rest_array)
    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
    writer.writerows(cursor)

cursor.close()
conn.close()

print 'All done for now'
```

The error:

```
writer.writerows(cursor)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Have you searched for previous questions like this? There is one that is identical, with a Python 2.x solution, here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40619675/4451406

Comment: I have edited my snippet to show the suggestion. I tried the suggestion on the link Irmen but it gave another message. rest_array = [text.encode("utf8") for text in cursor]
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: First convert the result row into the appropriate str type(s). You're attempting to write a Row result object directly into the csv

Comment: Irmen, sorry if this may sound amateur (I am a beginner Python user),how can I do what you are suggesting.

Comment: You're selecting stuff from a table in your database. The result from the select query is some database *rows* (of type ``pyodbc.Row`` apparently). You'll have to extract the columns from them and turn those values into strings first, before you can encode them properly into your csv file (which is essentially just string values separated by comma).     I don't know what's in your table so I can't tell you how to get the columns from the rows, that is a different question entirely than the problem you asked about here. Look up the documentation of pyodbc and look at your database schema.

Comment: @ Learner, Have you tried the unicodecsv module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably install and use the unicodecsv module.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1